keen-ui not found after installation in vue 3 app
I am working in a vue 3 app, I want to use the keen-ui 1.3.1 library and i have this Could not find a declaration file for module 'keen-ui'. 'c:route/to/project/node_modules/keen-ui/dist/keen-ui.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try npm i --save-dev @types/keen-ui if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'keen-ui';ts(7016) when I try to import it in my component : import { UiPopover } from 'keen-ui' . I am not using typescript.
I´ve read the docs here https://github.com/JosephusPaye/Keen-UI/tree/master#keen-ui, did as it says, and nothing

What I did was to place import KeenUI from 'keen-ui' import 'keen-ui/dist/keen-ui.css' app.use(KeenUI) in the main.js file and after that I can import any component like <ui-button> or <ui-pop-over> but having the same message when hover on the 'keen-ui' when importing.
